# R: Error in data.frame . . . arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Tags: r

I am trying to run a simple loop to download Snotel data for every available site using the snotelr package.

```
library(snotelr)
library(dplyr)
SnowMetaData <- snotel_info()
SnowData <- do.call(dplyr::bind_rows, lapply(SnowMetaData$site_id, function(thisSite){
  cat(thisSite, fill = T)
  snotel_download(site_id = thisSite,
               internal = TRUE) %>%
    return()
  }))
```

but I'm getting an "Error in data.frame(meta_data[i, ], df) :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0" message. It works if I only run the first 2 sites as a test, though.

```
SnowMetaData <- snotel_info()
SnowData <- do.call(dplyr::bind_rows, lapply(SnowMetaData$site_id[1:2], function(thisSite){
  cat(thisSite, fill = T)
  snotel_download(site_id = thisSite,
               internal = TRUE) %>%
    return()
  }))
```

I have read basically every other StackOverflow question about this error and can't solve it. Help please?

Comment: The `snotel_info()`triggers my firewall. Could you provide the output of it with `dput(SnowData)` ?

Comment: @Julien https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ux3GmszeLfbPzLhOkF5y8deMc5oDG6eNA33bBgX0ySY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've got the error `Error in snotel_download(site_id = thisSite, internal = TRUE) : 
could not find function "snotel_download"`. Does this function is part of the  `snotelr` package ?

Comment: In fact I meant `dput(SnowMetaData)`. Is that the dataframe that you provided ?

Comment: I am still installing the `snotelr` package. Meanwhile, can you tell me which part of the code produces the error : `lapply()` or `do.call()` ?

Comment: It runs fine on my computer

Comment: @Julien I still can't get it to work, were you able to run it with all 896 site IDs? Or just the first few?

Comment: The `site_id` column has only 577 elements in the data provided